# Sql query graph parentheses, what's their use

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking at several SQL queries inside a PHP software and always see the parameters inside graph parentheses.
What is their use and why does SQL correctly runs with them apparently ignoring them?

```
$q = "INSERT INTO COMMENT (NAME, MAIL, WEBSITE, COMMENT)
            VALUES('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$website}', '{$comment}')";
```

Comment: what are graph parentheses?

Comment: its not sql its PHP that will first process your code inside the variable `$q` and will be sent to sql.

Comment: Ah, the life and times of string interpolation!

Comment: It is used for php parsing; if you are about to pass values to queries like this for ex `VALUES({$userData['Name']}` or with variable variables like `{$$name}`, also would like to note that using variable variable is not a good practice